# How to download SVN code?

Tags: svn, download, open-source

Ok so, there is this android open source project I want to compile and play around with.
Problem is that it's hosted on :
http://svn.felspar.com/public/m-intercept/trunk/
or
http://svn.felspar.com/public/m-intercept/trunk/

Which only let me download file by file.. how do I download the whole thing so I can use it in eclipse ? ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to checkout from the repository. This [link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) would help you out.